# Alternative to DUPLICATE ON UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I was wondering if there is a alternative to duplicate on update, which does not ignore the update.
The idea is users can insert data into a database (via a form) and can later come back to edit the data (which would then update). When using the duplicate on update i had a primary key and a index key (as you can see below), and all the duplicate on update statement did was continue to insert new rows to the db . I can know longer afford to spend anymore time on this so was wondering if there was a alternative method.

```
CREATE TABLE `Product` (
`Product_Id` bigint(255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Resturant_ID` bigint(255) NOT NULL,
`Product_Desc` text NOT NULL,
`Product_Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`Product_Price` decimal(4,3) NOT NULL,
`Add_On_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Product_Id`),
KEY `Resturant_ID` (`Resturant_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: You must not spend many time. So if **ANY** unique Key can use for. You only must define a **UNIQUE KEY** over the fields where mysql can find the duplication. if the Resturant_ID the KEY you must change it to unique

Comment: @BerndBuffen i have just found my big mistake i made the Resturant_ID and Product_Name unique key together. so no restaurant can have the same product_name

Comment: great. is it works now ?

Comment: @BerndBuffen it works perfectly